# choose and option steps in Cosmos DB gremlin API

Tags: gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

Although `choose` is not on the [list of supported gremlin steps for Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin-support#gremlin-steps) (as well as some others) it seems to be supported. Given an example graph with people it a query like

```
g.V().hasLabel('person').choose(values('name'))
.option('josh', constant('it's Josh!'))
```

returns a json array `['Josh!']`. Adding more option also works e.g.

```
g.V().hasLabel('person').choose(values('name'))
.option('josh', constant('it's Josh!'))
.option('marco', constant('it's marco!'))
```

but what doesnt seem to work is using `Pick.none`/ `none` for specifying a default case as described in the [gremlin docs for `choose`](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#choose-step) e.g.

```
g.V().hasLabel('person').choose(values('name'))
.option('josh', constant('it's Josh!'))
.option('marco', constant('it's marco!'))
.option(none, constant('it's somebody else!'))
```

Does anybody know how to specify the default case in Cosmos DB? I already tried any permutation containing `Pick` and/or `none` that I could think of e.g. `Pick.none`, `Pick().none()`, `none`, `none()`, ...

Comment: Did you find the way to use `Pick` in cosmos ?